# How to sanitize a string in google appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an endpoint in Google appengine in java for letting user send me a message on my website.

The endpoint are generating with google SDK from a class like :

```
  @Entity
  public class Message {}
```

The message is persist with :

```
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    mgr.persist(message);
```

How can i sanitize the string before persist it ?

I found this related post :[Handling of HTML forms in App Engine (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842858/handling-of-html-forms-in-app-engine-java)

In advance thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can sanitize the text string using an existing library like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) (#clean).

The choice of the specific tool depends on your requirements, but writing your own utility to sanitize text is not that simple unless you allow no tags at all.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the library i can use in javascript. THanks for learning e the term sanitize. Do you know some java librairies compatible with appengine that can do this ? For have a check server side.

Comment: jsoup is a java library that is compatible with app engine. I would recommend doing all of your sanitation on the server side. It is secure that way. If you sanitize in javascript, then it is not secure